# Find variable name with string input

Tags: c#

If I have a ton of int arrays for example in a method and I input a string is there a way of finding the variable name that corresponds to that string and then returning that array?

Comment: I don't understand, can you improve the explanation? Maybe a example can help?

Comment: Maybe put your arrays in a dictionary?

Comment: Show us the code, please.

Comment: What did you try so far? Add a clear example; otherwise, it will be hard to help you. How is your problem different from using a `Dictionary<string, int[]>`, which would be an obvious solution for accessing arrays by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a `Dictionary<string, int[]>`.

Where the key (string) will be the name for each array (value).

Then you can search by the dictionary key, e.g:

```
string input = <Your Input>;
IDictionary<string, int[]> arraysDic = 
   <Initialize with the arrays you have and a name for each array>;

if (arraysDic.ContainsKey(input))
{
    return arraysDic[input];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no built-in way to access a *local variable* just by its name. In fact, local variable names are often changed by the compiler or inlined away, so it would not be stable.

I would recommend using a different data structure than "a ton of int arrays" if you need to access them dynamically. A dictionary seems like a reasonable choice, or a class or struct to hold the arrays.

Another option if you have variables like `array1`, `array2`, `array3`... would be to use a `List` of arrays and access them by index instead of by name.

Comment: To support your first paragraph, the local variable names aren't even part of the compiled assemblies (`.dll`/`.exe`); they're encoded as part of the debugging information (`.pdb`).